# Offline state not rehydrating with redux-offline

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using redux-offline in order to handle offline interactions inside my application. The offline state in my redux store is not being persisted when the app is restarted.

For example, my application is offline, and a user interacts with the app in a way that calls an action to be dispatched. Redux-offline diverts the action to the outbox array in the offline state of the redux store, which should retry the action when the application comes back online. If I do this and have an action queued in the offline state, then restart the app (while still offline), the redux store persists everything except the offline state, therefore I am losing the items I had queued.

My store configuration code is as follows. I have written it in a way so that a splash screen is displayed until the redux store is rehydrated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { autoRehydrate, persistStore } from "redux-persist"
import logger from "redux-logger"
import { offline } from "redux-offline"
import offlineConfig from "redux-offline/lib/defaults"
import reducers from "./redux/modules"
import MyApp from "./MyApp"
import SplashScreen from "./components/home/SplashScreen"

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  undefined,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger), offline(offlineConfig))
)

export default class Setup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rehydrated: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
  }

  render = () =>
    !this.state.rehydrated ? (
      <SplashScreen />
    ) : (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApp />
      </Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check with redux tools - probably offline store is rehydrated, but it is changed right away by event that setup it state, update to lastest redux-offline should fix it